# How can I print a variable of type cufftDoubleComplex?

Tags: c++, cuda, printf, complex-numbers

How can I print a variable of type `cufftDoubleComplex` in CUDA C++, I tried doing this using `printf`:

```
cufftDoubleComplex Fd;
printf("%f", Fd); //not working
```

but I got this error and it didn't work during runtime:

> warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%f' requires an argument of type 'double', but variadic argument 1 has type 'cufftDoubleComplex'

How can I print it? What is the proper format string to use inside `printf`?

Comment: A quick glance at an online copy of `cuComplex.h` suggests the `cuCreal()` and `cuCimag()` functions for accessing the real and imaginary parts of a CUDA complex number. Printing those is trivial.

Comment: C++ doesn't define `printf` format specifiers for complex data types. A complex number comprises a real and imaginary part. You need to retrieve the two parts and print them separately. Header file `cuComplex.h` exports `cuCreal()` and `cuCimag()` for this purpose.

Comment: It worked fine in addition to @gct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be layout compatible with double[2], so just cast it and print the two fields:

```
printf("re: %f  im: %f\n", ((double*)&Fd)[0], ((double*)&Fd)[1]);
```

This isn't "safe safe" but since CuFFT promises to be compatible with fftw, the layout of the type is guaranteed to be compatible in this way.

Edit, this is preferable, cufftDoubleComplex is a typedef of cuDoubleComplex which just has two fields x,y (bad names):

```
printf("re: %f  im: %f\n", Fd.x, Fd.y);
```

Comment: Both worked fine, in addition to @Shawn and @njuffa suggestion `cuCreal` &`cuCimag`, but I preferred your second direct answer; `Fd.x` &`Fd.y`.

Comment: I suppose theoretically they could change the names of those fields someday, but I think the likliehood of that is very very low

Comment: I hope they do. I think what did this was a programmer not a mathematician.

Comment: It's aliased to a double2 which is just a 2 vector, so I can see why it happened, still.